# EventHandlers & Multiple Class Instance & Overlapping variables C#

Tags: c#

For multiple instances, when event handlers are declared like below, do they tend to overlap and set all the instances of a variables

For say,

```
Something class = new Something();
```

is declared ~ 3 times and on all 3 times, the eventhandlers are declared and used.

```
    public class something
    {
    public string str = "1";
public string str2 = "2";
        public void onconnect(object sender, ConnectedEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.Connected)
                    {
                        this.ses = e.NetworkSession;
                        this.ses.OnHandshakeHandler += new EventHandler<HSEventArgs>(OnHandshakeHandler);
                        this.ses.onreceive+= new EventHandler<PEventArgs>(onreceive);
                        return;
                    }
            }
    }
```

now lets say

```
 public void onreceive(object sender, PEventArgs e)
{
str = "3";
}
```

Would str all be turned to "3" onrecieve? Because in my case, i'm starting to believe the eventhandler is shared between all instances of the class. Therefore rendering all variables in all instances of the class to be the same.

If this is not the case, could eventhandlers be the reason behind why my variables are all getting changed by the same event raised?
If so, how would you isolate the class and assign the handler to each individual class?

onconnect is called by

```
    public void Connect(string ip, short port)
    {
        try
        {
            this.connector = new Connector();
            this.connector.OnClientConnected += new EventHandler<ConnectedEventArgs>(onConnect);
            this.connector.Connect(ip, port); //Logs into server
        }
        catch
        {
            updateLog("[Error]Servers exploded!!!", this);
        }

    }
```

and ^ is called when a button is pushed on a gui

Comment: That depends on how `onconnect()` is called. How is it called?

Comment: `ses` is not declared, is `onconnect` supposed to be subscribed to some undefined `Connect` event?

Comment: ses is declared when the something class is called.
it is declared with 

        public Session ses = new Session(null);

Comment: I suspect that when the event fires, the handler in each class is handling it. If you put a breakpoint in the handler, does it get hit n times or once?

Comment: if the code you post can be used to recreate the problem in your question it makes it easier to give a good answer.

Comment: it is only hit once. that's why i suspected it had something to do with the eventhandlers

Answer (score 1):

If I read the documentation correctly (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975820.aspx) there will be one `NetworkSession` per user. You are one user, so you have one `NetworkSession`.

You created three instances of `Something`, and I get the feeling they are all called by the same event: the software os connected to the game network.

All 3 `onconnect` methods get in `e` the same instance of `NetworkSession` and you connect your eventhanlder `onreceive` to `NetworkSession.onreceive`.

So if the NetworkSession receives something, all the 3 eventhandlers of your 3 instances are called.

The creating a seperate `NetworkSession` per instance by using `NetworkSession.BeginCreate` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.networksession.begincreate.aspx).

Comment: what would be your suggestion to isolate this?